# Can I get dependencies.child-chart.version from Helm template?

Tags: helm, kubernetes-helm

I have this tree:

```
 environments
 ┣ staging
 ┃ ┣ Chart.yaml
 ┃ ┗ values.yaml
 services
 ┣ my-service
 ┃ ┣ helm
 ┃ ┃ ┣ templates
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ deployment.yaml
 ┃ ┃ ┣ Chart.yaml
 ┃ ┃ ┗ values.yaml
```

`environments/staging/Chart.yaml` look like this:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: staging
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.0.0"
dependencies:
  - name: my-service
    repository: file://../../services/my-service/helm
    version: 79947968d75f9b728b321b070d12eaacd12636ca-SNAPSHOT
```

`environments/staging/values.yaml` look like this:

```
my-service:
  image:
    tag: 79947968d75f9b728b321b070d12eaacd12636ca-SNAPSHOT
```

`services/my-service/helm/templates/deployment.yaml` look like this:

```
...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
...
```

There is a way to access to `dependencies.my-service.version` from my "child" deployment template, with something like this ?

```
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Chart.Dependencies.my-service.version }}"
```

If not (what I guess), do you please have tips to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/)

> A subchart is considered "stand-alone", which means a subchart can
> never explicitly depend on its parent chart. For that reason, a
> subchart cannot access the values of its parent. A parent chart can
> override values for subcharts. Helm has a concept of global values
> that can be accessed by all charts.

I believe the best approach will be to maintain any shared values under the `global` section